# What is buffer_size in keyword_tokenizer in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Here's the documentation:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-tokenizer.html

It says:

> The term buffer size. Defaults to 256.

Does that mean my token can be max 256 symbols long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The buffer size is just the size of the chunks it reads in from the input stream.  Unless you have a reason to do otherwise, you can generally ignore it and leave it as the default.